# pyRenamer does not rename some Huawei P20 images

Tags: file-management, linux

I'm using **pyRenamer** for many years without problems. Now I have some images from Huawei P20 camera and pyRenamer does not rename approx. 10% of the images. Instead of Date and Time, I get underline instead. The rename pattern I use for many years is:

```
`{imageyear}-{imagemonth}-{imageday}_{imagetime}_{rand1000-9999,4}_{cameramaker}_{cameramodel}.JPG`
```

After some research, I found out that

- approx. 90% of all images does not have a description. pyRenamer works well with this files (left side of screenshot)
- approx. 10% of all images have a description (right side of screenshot). All files seems to have a hexadecimal description.

[image]

My guess is that the `description` tag is the reason why pyRenamer does not work. Any ideas why Huawei adds a hexadecimal description tag into some images? Now, how can I remove the description tag of the images? Bash commands welcome.

Comment: Perhaps the description tag isn't there, and pyRenamer is misreading the image data and calling it "description"? Install `exiftool`, and run `exiftool -s ImageDescription <file.jpg>` on the files that pyRenamer says has a "description" tag. Does `exiftool` report the same information?

Comment: I've run `exiftool -s FOV <FILENAME>` and there is a description tag in "bad" image. 
Comparing the EXIF Informations of the two images gave me following differences: 
"good" Image has an empty `DocumentName                    : `. 
"good" Image has tag `DeviceSettingDescription        : (Binary data 4 bytes, use -b option to extract)`.

Comment: "bad" Image has `ImageDescription                : 0590efa16b43c0871d88a7f1412e8696174ac08a1f3b2c23ef11da74d5ea1076`. 
* "bad" Image has some additional GPS Tags: `GPSAltitude`, `GPSDateTime`, `GPSLatitude`, `GPSLongitude`, `GPSPosition`, `GPSLatitudeRef`, `GPSAltitudeRef`, `GPSProcessingMethod`, `GPSVersionID`, `GPSLongitudeRef`, `GPSTimeStamp`, `GPSDateStamp`.
My gues iss still that the `ImageDescription` tag is causing the problems. Is it possible to remove it with exiftool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exiftool` is probably the best multi-purpose tool for working with and manipulating image metadata.

You can remove undesired tags from image files using,

```
exiftool -overwrite_original -P -ImageDescription= <file.jpg>
```

If modifying or deleting tags in an image file, `exiftool` normally writes the resulting file to a temporary output file, so as not to clobber the original file; the `-overwrite_original` option causes it to write over the original file.

The `-P` option preserves the original file’s *filesystem* creation and modification time stamps (nothing to do with the image’s date-related EXIF tags). If you don’t care about preserving this file information, you can omit this option.

`exiftool` accepts multiple file names and wildcard file names, so you can easily batch this command to preprocess all of your problematic file.

Comment: I slightly modified your command `exiftool -overwrite_original -P -ImageDescription='' <file.jpg>` (added paragraph after `=` ). Then, the strange `ImageDescription` value disappeared, but `pyRenamer` was still unable to rename image files. So I took your advice to modify the images with `exiftool` on command line:  `exiftool -P -'Filename<${DateTimeOriginal}_0000_${Make}_${Model}'.%ue -d %Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S%%-c` gave me exactly the file name I was looking for.